# Creating animal models

Tags: research-design

I was wondering how a scientist in a lab may know which type of animal model to use. I have been looking at the effect of a protein on a disease. And have thought about the ways that’s i know this has been done in other research- 
- deletion of gene which encodes for protein
- insert GFP by Gene for protein leaving gene intact
- or insert gfp by gene for protein deleting the gene
However I cannot seem to understand how a scientist decides to choose a certain model?

Comment: Hi Beth and welcome to Bio.SE! Could you link the paper you are describing in the experiments, and narrow down the question? Currently, it sounds like you are asking a very broad question about animal experimental design and then describing a molecular biology experiment.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of a model organism as this can be found on the [Nature](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/model-organism-model-genetic-organism-139/) Homepage, this clarifies quite a lot:

> An organism suitable for studying a specific trait, disease, or
>   phenomenon, due to its short generation time, characterized genome, or
>   similarity to humans; examples are a fly, fish, rodent or pig, whose
>   biology is well known and accessible for laboratory studies.

So you want an organism, that:

- can be bred in large numbers
- has a sufficiently short generation time, so you can analyze several generations of it
- is well characterized
- sufficiently close to the organism you want to learn more about (mostly: Humans), so the findings can be transfered
- can be mutated and has your gene/protein/etc. of interest
- has been sequenced completely

Besides this general considerations, practical ones also play a role. If you don't have a fish facility on hand, you will most likely not start using zebrafish as your animal model.

There are certainly more requirements, see one of the references.

References:

1. [Requirements and selection of an animal model.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/19844411_Requirements_and_selection_of_an_animal_model)
2. [Selecting appropriate animal models and strains: Making the best use
   of research, information and outreach](http://www.asas.or.jp/jsaae_old/zasshi/WC6_PC/paper303.pdf)
3. [Basic Principles in Selecting Animal Species for Research Projects](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3109/15563657808988266)